# Manage water flow with Arduino

Tags: animation, mantaflow

I have made an animation with a water flow. I want it to start and stop  with Arduino, I have thought about making it with a sensor that triggers the animation of "start and stop". Is it possible to do that? I have seen that the animation of the "start and stop" flow only works if you refresh the cash. And I was thinking that maybe a sensor is not enough, cause I need it to start and stop the flow (so trigger the keyframes I suppose) and I believe that I need to refresh the cash. Is blender appropriate to make this project or I should stick to another software? If it's appropriate, what should I do? I'm new to Arduino.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for this site since it seems to be more related to Arduino instead of Blender...

Comment: I think the question is OK here, because it's about stuff that happens in Blender. I'll attempt an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Blender could interact with Arduino, because Blender has [Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/). You could use [Pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) to communicate with your Arduino via serial connection through USB. You would need to install this external Python module to Blender's Python - see [Using 3rd party Python modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules).

If it's a playing animation you need to somehow interact with, you could check serial on every frame change using an [Application Handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#module-bpy.app.handlers):

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    #Serial communication could happen here
    print("Frame change")

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
```

I haven't tested any of this, so this is only a possible solution, that you would need to look into and you might face some unforeseen problems, but I think this should be possible.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56453/receive-serial-data-in-background) about serial communication might be of interest to you as well.